# Routing error in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new to Ruby on Rails
I am getting this error

> uninitialized constant WelcomeController

after creating the sample project. I enabled

```
root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

in routes.rb.

Comment: I also got this error when using the getting started guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html You have to actually change the line to home#index like Mohan Raj says in his comment below. You don't just un-comment the line.

Answer (score 12):

When you say

```
root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

you're telling Rails to send all requests for `/` to the `index` method in `WelcomeController`. The error message is telling you that you didn't create your `WelcomeController` class. You should have something like this:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # whatever your controller needs to do...
  end
end
```

in `app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb`.

Comment: Hi i found the solution just i changed root :to => 'home#index'. I created the controller home. So set route to home.

Comment: @MohanRaj you should accept this answer as correct, as it is.

Answer (score 5):

I'm very very new to Rails and also ran into this error while following along with Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. The problem I had was that in the `config/routes.rb` file, I just uncommented the `root :to => "welcome#index"`:

```
# just remember to delete public/index.html.
root :to => "welcome#index"
```

but with the structure of the sample_app was that "welcome#index" should be 'pages#home' instead, since everything was originally set up through the "pages" controller.

```
root :to => 'pages#home'
```

It's even right there in the book, but I just overlooked it and spent quite a while afterwards trying to figure out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure WelcomeController is defined in a file called welcome_controller.rb

Answer (score 1):

`rails generate controller welcome index`

Comment: The generator sets the route for you.
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
end

Answer (score 1):

If you not generate the page with name `welcome`, then just generate the page like:  `$ rails generate controller pagename index`. So then into the: **config->routes.rb** you should edit **root 'welcome#index'** to **root 'pagename#index'**

Answer (score 0):

Keep this if you want it to be your context root after you generate your welcome parts.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: Years late and thousands short. :-)